# LINQ - Grouping a list by multiple properties and returning an object with an array member

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, group-by, google-visualization

This is going to be a two part question.

I am trying to build a data structure for use with the Google Charts API (specifically, their data table).

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
return Json.Encode(
    RMAs
    .Where(r => r.CreatedDate.Year > DateTime.Now.Year - 4) //Only grab the last 4 years worth of RMAs
    .GroupBy(r => new { Problem = r.Problem, Year = r.CreatedDate.Year, Quarter = ((r.CreatedDate.Month) / 3) })
    .Select(r => new { Problem = r.Key.Problem, Year = r.Key.Year, Quarter = r.Key.Quarter, Count = r.Count() })
);
```

This gets me very close.  This gets me an array similar to the following:

```
{"Problem":"It broke!","Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":3},
{"Problem":"It broke!","Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":1}
```

But, what I want is for the data to be grouped further by the "Problem" property so that the quarter is an array for each problem (this makes the data structure much easier to iterate over).  An example of the desired structure:

```
{"Problem":"It broke!",
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":3},
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":1}
},
{"Problem":"Some other problem",
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":31}
}
```

The second part of the question:  How can I ensure that I have data for each quarter (again, this makes it *much* easier to iterate over for building the data table with the API), even if a "Problem" did not occur in that quarter?  Using the same example as last time:

```
{"Problem":"It broke!",
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":3},
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":1}
},
{"Problem":"Some other problem",
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":0}
    {"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":31}
}
```

Comment: In the second part of your question, are you filtering out year/quarter combinations that had no problems (i.e. Year=2012, Quarter=3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the following to your query:

   ```
   .GroupBy(x => x.Problem)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x=>new { Year=x.Year, Quarter=x.Quarter, Count = x.Count }));
   ```
2. You have to insert the following before .ToDictionary() above:

   ```
   .Select(g =>
     new { 
       Key = g.Key, 
       Items = 
         g
           .GroupBy(r => r.Year)
           .SelectMany(gy =>
             gy.Concat(
               Enumerable.Range(1,5)
                 .Where(q => !gy.Any(r=>r.Quarter == q))
                 .Select(q => new { Problem = g.Key, Year = gy.Key, Quarter = q, Count = 0 })
             )
           )
     }
   )
   ```

I think... try it out :)

I would advise against following this approach, however, and create "empty" records on the client, to avoid excessive bandwidth use.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Mr. TA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428811/mr-ta) for the inspiration and for showing me that you can use LINQ against a grouping.

I have tested this out in a local environment and the LINQ does indeed return a list of Problems tied to an array of Year/Quarter groupings with a total Count.  I don't know if Json.Encode encodes it in the correct format though.

The following LINQ should return an anonymous type that fits the format you needed:

**Edit:** Query now returns count=0 for quarters where at least one problem occurred, but specified problem did not occur

```
var quarters = RMAs
    .Where(rma => rma.CreatedDate.Year > DateTime.Now.Year - 4)
    .GroupBy(rma => new { 
        Year = rma.CreatedDate.Year, 
        Quarter = ((rma.CreatedDate.Month) / 3) 
    });

return Json.Encode(
    RMAs
        //Only grab the last 4 years worth of RMAs
        .Where(r => r.CreatedDate.Year > DateTime.Now.Year - 4)
        // Group all records by problem     
        .GroupBy(r => new { Problem = r.Problem })
        .Select(grouping => new
            {
                Problem = grouping.Key.Problem,
                Occurrences = quarters.Select(quarter => new
                    {
                        Year = quarter.Key.Year,
                        Quarter = quarter.Key.Quarter,
                        Count = grouping
                                .GroupBy(record => new
                                {
                                    Year = record.CreatedDate.Year,
                                    Quarter = ((record.CreatedDate.Month) / 3)
                                })
                                .Where(record => 
                                    record.Key.Year == quarter.Key.Year 
                                    && record.Key.Quarter == quarter.Key.Quarter
                                ).Count()
                    }).ToArray()
            }));
```

**Update:** Thanks to [JamieSee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015164/jamiesee) for updating with example JSON output:

This is an example of the JSON output:

```
[{"Problem":"P","Occurrences":[{"Year":2012,"Quarter":4,"Count":2},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":1},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":1}]},{"Problem":"Q","Occurrences":[{"Year":2012,"Quarter":3,"Count":1},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":1},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":1}]}]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I added an example of actual JSON produced by your code. Looks like you and I had pretty much the same idea.

Comment: @JamieSee - Thanks!  I've never worked with JSON, so I modified the code to store the results in a variable and print it to the console to see if it looks like the correct structure.  I didn't get a chance to see if the actual Json.Encode call worked.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question completely? The 2nd part asks about returning info for quarters without any problems, which your solution doesn't do.

Comment: The updated solution should now include the 2nd part.  As per the example it is not including year/quarter combinations that had no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full restatement to meet all your criteria:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetQuarterDates()
{
    for (DateTime quarterDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4); quarterDate <= DateTime.Now; quarterDate = quarterDate.AddMonths(3))
    {
        yield return quarterDate; 
    }
}

public static void RunSnippet()
{
    var RMAs = new[] {
        new { Problem = "P", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2012, 6, 2) },
        new { Problem = "P", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 7) },
        new { Problem = "P", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 8) },
        new { Problem = "P", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 8, 1) },
        new { Problem = "P", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1) },
        new { Problem = "Q", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 11, 11) },
        new { Problem = "Q", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 6, 6) },
        new { Problem = "Q", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2011, 3, 3) }
    };

    var quarters = GetQuarterDates().Select(quarterDate => new { Year = quarterDate.Year, Quarter = Math.Ceiling(quarterDate.Month / 3.0) });

    var rmaProblemQuarters = from rma in RMAs
            where rma.CreatedDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4)
            group rma by rma.Problem into rmaProblems
            select new {
                            Problem = rmaProblems.Key,
                            Quarters = (from quarter in quarters
                                        join rmaProblem in rmaProblems on quarter equals new { Year = rmaProblem.CreatedDate.Year, Quarter = Math.Ceiling(rmaProblem.CreatedDate.Month / 3.0) } into joinedQuarters
                                        from joinedQuarter in joinedQuarters.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        select new {
                                                        Year = quarter.Year,
                                                        Quarter = quarter.Quarter,
                                                        Count = joinedQuarters.Count()
                                                   })
                       };

    string json = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(rmaProblemQuarters);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Which yields:

```
[{"Problem":"P","Quarters":[{"Year":2008,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2008,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2008,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":2,"Count":1},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":3,"Count":1},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":4,"Count":2},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":4,"Count":2},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":1}]},{"Problem":"Q","Quarters":[{"Year":2008,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2008,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2008,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2009,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":2,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2010,"Quarter":4,"Count":0},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":1,"Count":1},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":2,"Count":1},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":3,"Count":0},{"Year":2011,"Quarter":4,"Count":1},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":1,"Count":0},{"Year":2012,"Quarter":2,"Count":0}]}]
```

Comment: Similarly to JonSenchyna, your answer doesn't solve the question's 2nd part.

Comment: Updated the answer to meet the empty quarter criteria. Also, I've restated it in Linq syntax rather than Linq method calls because it was getting hard to read.